# How to show data outside of a subscribe scope/ how to use callback

Tags: javascript, angular, callback

I want to show a list from an API call.

```
let url = 'api/list';
this.apiService.get<List[]>(url)
.subscribe((response) => {
  this.list = response; // response has data
})
console.log(this.list); // no data shown
```

Because of async behavior the console always shows a blank list. How can I show the list with data outside of the subscribe scope. For clarification I need the list with data in the consoles position. I am familiar with the concept of callback. Do I need to use a callback function here? If yes, how can I achieve that?

Comment: You already use a callback here.

Comment: To access asynchronous data from an Observable you _must_ subscribe to that Observable. Unless you put the console.log inside the subscription, the only other way to access that data would be "hackily" dropping the console.log inside a `setTimeout` which I would not recommend unless you're simply debugging as it will only give you the value emitted closest to your setTimeout call, and not the entire timeline of the Observable.

Answer (score -3):

The object the keyword `this` is pointing to is different in the places you are using it. So when you are setting `this.list` inside your callback function, you are setting the attribute `list` of your callback function.

One old skool way to fix this would be setting `let that = this` and then inside your callback function using `that.list`. By doing so you would be setting the attribute `list` of the keyword `this` that is one level above your callback function.

Hope it still makes some kind of sense.

Also look at Andrew Hills comment, it's full of logic :)

Comment: No, it isn't. Your answer is based on false assumptions.

Comment: The fat arrow (`=>`) syntax properly binds the `this` context. Only the old `function ()` syntax needs the `var that = this` hack.

Comment: Right, thanks for this. So this was introduced with ecma6?